# JTextfield Listener for Integers

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I am having troubles in finding a solution to write a listener for a `JTextField` specifically to only allow integer values (No `String`s allowed). I've tried [this recommended link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) on Document Listener, but I don't know what method to invoke etc.

I've never used this type of Listener before, so could anyone explain how I could write a listener on a `JTextField` to only allow integer values that can be accepted?

Basically after I click a `JButton`, and before the data is extracted out onto a variable, then Listener will not allow it to be processed until an integer is inputted.

Thanks very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a document listener.  You want an ActionListener on the submit/ok button.

Make sure that listener is created with a handle to the JTextField, then put this code in the `actionPerformed` call:

```
int numberInField;
try {
  numberInField = Integer.parseInt(myTextField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
  //maybe display an error message;
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad Input", "Field 'whatever' requires an integer value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  return;
}
// you have a proper integer, insert code for what you want to do with it here
```

Comment: OK thanks. I actually have been using parseInt. But is there a way that if you tried to input a String, then a tooktip of somesort will pop up and say 'Only ints required (JTextField wont allow input)? Or is that too complex to write it in java? Thanks again

Comment: You can pop up an error message in the catch clause above, or else put a JLabel into your dialog for displaying an error message.  Which will look better depends on what else you have there, but generally speaking popups are disruptive. [edited to include an error dialog]

Comment: OK thanks for the help. Dialog box is the best solution. Thanks again

Comment: You want to use a JFormattedTextField or a DocumentFilter so only valid digits can be entered. Then you don't even need to do an edit, unless you have a range condition of some king. For error messages you wouldn't use a JDialog, you would use a JOptionPane.

Comment: @camickr I think you put this comment in the wrong place.  I already use a JOptionPane in my answer to make the error dialog.

Comment: The main point about the comment was to use a `JFormattedTextField` or a `DocumentFilter`.  The poster also mentioned "dialog box is best solution". I wanted to clarify it should be a JOptionPane.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a listener, you want to get the text from the `JTextField` and test if it is an `int`.

```
if (!input.getText().trim().equals(""))
{
    try 
    {
        Integer.parseInt(myString);
        System.out.println("An integer"):
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException) 
    {
        // Not an integer, print to console:
        System.out.println("This is not an integer, please only input an integer.");
        // If you want a pop-up instead:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Invalid input. Enter an integer.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

You could also use a regex (a little bit of overkill, but it works):

```
boolean isInteger = Pattern.matches("^\d*$", myString);
```

Comment: @DouglasGrealis You would put something like that in your `catch`. I'll update my example.

Comment: OK thanks. I can use a dialog box in the catch clause. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> how I could write a listener on a JTextField to only allow integer values that can be accepted?

You should be using a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or a [Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Answer (score 1):

JFormattedTextField example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    format.setGroupingUsed(false);
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
    formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    formatter.setMinimum(0);
    formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field);
}
```

`JFormattedTextField` works well for restricting input. In addition to limiting input to numbers, it is capable of more advanced use, e.g. phone number format. This provides immediate validation without having to wait for form submission or similar event.